# Pogo.com games won't work, says outdated java

Tags: java, google-chrome, games

I am trying to get my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop to be able to run games on pogo.com

First none of the games on pogo would work because of outdated flash. Then I learned of google chrome with pep flash and some of the games would work but not all of them due to outdated java.

I have iced tea plugin for my chrome but have no idea what versions of java it supports.

I need java7 to run the pogo online games, so i tried to install openjdk7 but it would not show up on my chrome plugins. If anyone could help me figure out this problem it would be much appreciated.

[image: screenshoot]

Also, I am using chromes newest download straight from google, with iced-tea 1.2.3.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshoot showing us the error please?

Comment: I have tried openjdk7, I have tried icedtea, I have tried Firefox, Chromium, and chrome. So far the only one to come close is chrome straight from google. I only say close because it only works on half of the games, but the games I am trying to play are the ones it doesn't want to work on. All pogo says is my java is outdated, nothing else, no specifics.

Answer (score 2):

There are [detailed instructions on java.com](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser_ubuntu.xml) covering Chrome and Firefox with Java 6 and Java 7.

To summarize:

1. Install Oracle JRE or JVM as 'usual' and locate the file `libnpjp2.so`(for example, under `$JRE_HOME/lib/amd64`.
2. Change directory to either `/opt/google/chrome/plugins` (for Chrome) or `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` (for Firefox) -- if this does not exist you need to create it (as root using `su` or `sudo`)
3. Become root using either `su` or `sudo` and create a symbolic link in the current directory to the file you located in Step 1. For example:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
   ```
4. Restart your browser

Comment: Updated with a summary.